# Run function after each() jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that the each() in jQuery is synchronous, but it doesn't seem to behaving that way. When I do this:

```
         $('#findRankBtn').click(function () {
             var websiteURL = $('#websiteURL').val();
             var searchTerms = $('#searchTerm').val();
             var pageNumber = $('#currentPage').val();

             //INSERTS A + FOR EVERY SPACE
             var searchTerms = searchTerms.replace(" ", "+");

             searchGoogle(searchTerms, pageNumber, websiteURL);



         });


         function searchGoogle(searchTerms, pageNumber, websiteURL) {
             $.getJSON("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyDPuIrijE0IQ6330vMLN2p-L_4J6y_G60c&cx=013036536707430787589:_pqjad5hr1a&q=" + searchTerms + "&alt=json&start=" + pageNumber,

             function (recievedData) {
                 //console.log(recievedData);
                 $.each(recievedData.items, function (i, item) {
                     $('#resultsDiv').append('<p class="resultLink">' + item.link + '</p>');
                     var linkAddress = $('.resultLink:last').text();
                     if (linkAddress.indexOf(websiteURL) !== -1) {
                         alert('found');
                         $('.resultLink:last').attr('class', 'yourLink');
                         $('#ifFound').attr('value', 'true');

                     }
                 });


                 var ifFound = $('#ifFound').val();
                 var currentPage = $('#currentPage').val();
                 var nextPage = CurrentPage + 1;
                 if (ifFound == 'false') {
                     //INCREMENT PAGE
                     $('#currentPage').attr('value', nextPage);

                     //GRAB DATA AGAIN
                     var websiteURL = $('#websiteURL').val();
                     var searchTerms = $('#searchTerm').val();
                     //INSERTS A + FOR EVERY SPACE
                     var searchTerms = searchTerms.replace(" ", "+");
                     //SEARCH GOOGLE
                     searchGoogle(searchTerms, nextPage);
                 }


             });
         }
```

Basically if it doesn't find the desired link on the first page of results, it should go on to the next page. I have a working fiddle for just the first page here: http://jsfiddle.net/p8DY3/1/
so how can I get searchGoogle() to run until it finds what it's looking for? 
Maybe there's a better way of going about it that's in the Google API that I don't know about?
Sorry if my question is amateur, I've only begun to learn JavaScript on my own a month ago.

Comment: So what is the actual problem? Is the code after your `$.each()` executing before the `$.each()` finishes iterating?

Comment: If it finds the link it runs this `$('#ifFound').attr('value', 'true');`, after each is ran, it should `$('#ifFound').val();` and if that's still false, it should run `searchGoogle()` again, but it doens't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should make sure you are not hitting some sort of rate limit from Google. Look at your Network tab to see if the requests are coming back correctly.

First issue I see is bad math.

var `currentPage = $('#currentPage').val();` is a string

Here `var nextPage = CurrentPage + 1;` you are treating it as a number.

You got to convert the string to a number before you add to it. You are doing string concatenation!.

```
var nextPage = parseInt(CurrentPage,10) + 1;
```

NITPICKS

Do not store things in inputs. Use variables, it will make things go so much faster. DOM lookup/manipulation is slow.

Why are you reinventing addClass and val()

```
$('.resultLink:last').attr('class', 'yourLink');
$('#currentPage').attr('value', nextPage);
```

should be

```
$('.resultLink:last').addClass('yourLink');
$('#currentPage').val(nextPage);
```

Why are you grabbing the search terms and website url again? You already have them passed into the function?

***Finally your problem***

```
searchGoogle(searchTerms, nextPage);  <-- What are you missing here?
function searchGoogle(searchTerms, pageNumber, websiteURL) {  <--what it is expecting
```

You are passing in 2 things when it wants 3.

Comment: I didn't know there were all of these cool things, fixing my code up now.